# Add querystring in return url in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, query-string

I have site which runs on three language. I am trying to set language querystring in url
for anonyumous request to **default culture**. I am using **authentication mode="Forms"** and **forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"** in web.config file. I want to set language querystring in like this

```
domainname.Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fcatalog%2fProduct.aspx%3fcatId%3d%26pId%3d6912%26l%3dru-RU?l=currentCulture.
```

I tried programmatically add langueage querystring like this

```
 var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
            var authenticationSection = (AuthenticationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");
            if (authenticationSection.Mode == AuthenticationMode.Forms)
            {

                authenticationSection.Forms.LoginUrl = "Login.aspx?l=" + Webiza.BLL.BizObject.CurrentCulture;
            }
```

but that didn't work. The only thing I could manage is set **loginUrl** property like this

```
forms loginUrl="Login.aspx?l=ru-RU"
```

,but I need l querystring to by set according to default culture.

How can I do it?

Comment: When ASP.NET sends your user to the logon page, it doesn't have the culture query string. After you detect the culture on page load, redirect the user to the logon page, this time with the culture as a parameter string.

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting an error like "This web page has a redirect loop"